# need a sql query to wrap text coming in differnt colums to one column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i am running the following query

```
SELECT ora_database_name AS SERVER_NAME,'CNTODSSTG' AS DB_NAME,p.owner,p.object_name,s.text 
FROM all_procedures p,all_source s 
WHERE p.owner<>'SYS' AND p.owner<>'SYSTEM' AND s.TYPE='PROCEDURE'
AND p.object_name=s.name
GROUP BY p.owner,p.object_name,s.text
```

s.text is the coding inside the procedure.
But it is coming in different lines 
I need to get it in one column 
Let me know how to modify above query to get required result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ora_database_name AS SERVER_NAME,
       'CNTODSSTG' AS DB_NAME,p.owner,p.object_name,
       dbms_metadata.get_ddl(p.object_type,p.object_name,p.owner)
FROM all_procedures p 
WHERE p.owner<>'SYS' AND p.owner<>'SYSTEM' AND s.TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the new lines characters with spaces

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(s_text, '[[:space:]]+', ' ') s_oneline_text
```

My idea there is that we deal with CR, LF, and spaces at beginning or end of line, replacing with a single space. This will also replace multiple space characters with a single space.